# Why does Android's onItemClick want a long for row Id?

Tags: java, android, listview, listener

For a listView, when you register an OnItemClickListener, the method you specify looks like this:

public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)

The id corresponds to the row that the user clicked on.  My question is simply why is it a long and not an int?  When would you use it as a long?  I've been casting it to an int when I use it, so it makes me think that maybe I'm using it wrong.

Comment: If you use a function to get the `id` that returns a long, don't cast it to an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this comes to us straight from [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> In SQLite, every row of every table
>   has an 64-bit signed integer ROWID.
>   The ROWID for each row is unique among
>   all rows in the same table.

Given that, it seems natural that the Android APIs would specify 64 bits for the ID for a database row.

Comment: if you use the ListView with for example a Cursor Adapter, the id parameter will hold the _id column of your result set. This makes further lookups etc. easy.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want more than several million rows.

Comment: You mean couple billion (2147483647 to be exact).

Comment: If you want to be technical, there is no reason for it to be signed, so double that #.